# problem loading image at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net

For some strange reason my picture is not loading at runtime:

```
        string path = Server.MapPath("./abc.jpeg");
        Response.Write("the path is:");
        Response.Write(path);

        img_ProfilePic.ImageUrl = path;
```

As you see from above code, I have verified that the path is correct.

Also the image is only 20 KB and is JPEG.

My environment is VS 2008 C#

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[`Server.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) returns the physical (file system) path.

`Image.ImageUrl` requires a virtual path (or relative/absolute URL). You should use it like this for example:

```
img_ProfilePic.ImageUrl = "~/images/abc.jpeg";
img_ProfilePic.ImageUrl = "../abc.jpeg";
img_ProfilePic.ImageUrl = "http://www.host.com/abc.jpeg";
```

---

More on web project paths (check the *Server Controls* section which is specific to your problem):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the "broken image" icon, and copy and paste the path into your browser.  Do you get the image, a "broken image" or a 404?

Are you testing locally?

Comment: Actually, you can disregard my answer. The other "Maxim Gueivandov" is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Replace string path = Server.MapPath("./abc.jpeg"); with string path = Server.MapPath("~/abc.jpeg");